# How to return boolean indexing Nan values as NaN and not false

Tags: pandas, boolean

I'm using this code

```
df['Bullish'] = (df['7days_Avg']>0.02).map(int)
```

as way of classification; 1 = True, 0 = False. 
However, when the column `df['7days_Avg']` doesn't have a value (NaN), I would also like the boolean value to have an output of 'Nan'

Below is the output I'm getting

```
            7days_Avg  Bullish  
Date                            
2017-02-23  -0.085974        0  
2017-02-24  -0.067239        0  
2017-02-27  -0.084491        0  
2017-02-28  -0.052741        0  
2017-03-01  -0.043309        0  
2017-03-02   0.092256        1  
2017-03-03   0.095302        1  
2017-03-06   0.069974        1  
2017-03-07   0.040541        1  
2017-03-08   0.005051        0  
2017-03-09   0.007219        0  
2017-03-10  -0.011321        0  
2017-03-13  -0.007576        0  
2017-03-14        NaN        0  
2017-03-15        NaN        0  
2017-03-16        NaN        0
```

As you can see, the column `Bullish` has the value  `0`for the last three rows, even though `7days_avg` has`Nan` values for the last three rows. I would like `Bullish` to also output `NaN` where `7days_avg row` values are `NaN`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `bullish` column doesn't already exist

```
sda = df['7days_Avg']
df.loc[sda.notnull(), 'Bullish'] = (sda > 0.02).map(int)
```

Comment: This works. Do you just create a new column ('Bullish') with df.loc? I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: I finally got around to understanding the code. Impressive stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Or, to keep it to one line, you can just reorder the code a tiny bit and use the map parameter na_action like this:

```
df['bullish'] = df['avg'].map(lambda x: int(x > 0.02), na_action='ignore')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the apply method?
Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def is_bullish(x):
    if x > 0.02:
        return True
    elif x <= 0.02:
        return False
    else:
        return np.NaN

df = pd.DataFrame({'avg': [np.random.randint(-10, 10)/100 for x in range(10)]})
df['avg'].ix[1] = None
print(df)
df['bullish'] = df['avg'].apply(is_bullish)
print(df)
```

I'm sure you could make the code more elegant, but this will work.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work, but the above code was a lot more precise.